# Need Help with Gitian-Builder - Missing Signer Error

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, altcoin-development, gitian

I'm having a hard time finishing this project. I'm very frustrated and I really need your help.

I'm trying to create the QT wallet for Windows & Linux.

I have already cloned a masternode and I'm stuck dealing with this error.

I have already installed the KVM virtual machine and the LXC.

So when I tried running the gitian-build.sh, I get the missing signer error. I have read that I dont need the signer unless is wrong info.

How do I fix this problem.

Thank You.

[image: Missing Signer - LXC]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `gitian-build.sh` script, you need to specify additional arguments for it to build and produce gitian signatures. You need to specify the version (or commit or branch) that you want to build. You must also specify an identifier for the GPG key that you want to use to sign the gitian output. That identifier is the signer.

For example, for me, I use the command

```
./gitian-build.sh -B --kvm 0.16.1 achow101
```

to build Linux, Windows, and MacOS binaries for 0.16.1 using kvm and signing the gitian output with the key `achow101`.